# How to do Operation Generator in Python using Lambda Functions

Tags: python

```
def make_multiplier(scaling_factor):
    return lambda x: mul(x, scaling_factor)

def make_exponentiator(exponent):
    return lambda x: pow(x, exponent)
```

mul takes two variables x , y and returns x * y. pow takes two variables x , y and returns x ^ y. Notice that these two functions are quite similar. We could abstract out the commonality into an even more general function make_generator such that we could then just write:

```
make_multiplier = make_generator(mul)
make_exponentiater = make_generator(pow)
```

Write the function make_generator.

Test Cases:

1. `make_multiplier(3)(2) = 6`
2. `make_exponentiator(3)(2) = 8`

My solution:

```
def make_generator(op):
    return lambda x, y: op(x, y)
#################
# DO NOT REMOVE #
#################

def mul(x,y):
    return x*y

def pow(x,y):
    return x**y

make_multiplier = make_generator(mul)
make_exponentiator = make_generator(pow)
```

I get the output but I do not pass the given test cases. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a test case the program does not pass?

Comment: Test Cases:

make_multiplier(3)(2) = 6
make_exponentiator(3)(2) = 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is supposed to take an operation and return a function that makes a function to use that operation with a fixed value (Kind of hard to wrap that around your head I know). While your current implementation just returns a function which takes two values and returns the result. Change your implementation as such:

```
def make_generator(op):
    def make_operation(fixed_value):
        return lambda x: op(x, fixed_value)
    return make_operation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lambda functions are quite interesting to learn about and this question stretched me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function like `f(x, y)` and you want to be able to call it like `g(x)(y)`, that is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). You can transform your lambda like this:

```py
# old version
return lambda x, y: op(x, y)

# curried version
return lambda x: lambda y: op(x, y)
```